# How to get the URL of the firebase I am connecting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am new to Firebase.I just opened `https://console.firebase.google.com` and I made a database **ng-recipe-book** and from where I can get the URL of the firebase I will connect to?

Recently,I am learning firebase from video and it setups the rule for read and write and when it switches the tab then URL to connect firebase is automatically appears.But in my context ,it is showing blank.How can I get the URL info?

It is the video tutor is teaching me:
[image]

But in my context ,it is shown as :
[image]

[image]

From,where I can see the URL to connect with the firebase?

Comment: You are creating a firestore db. Read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are using cloud firestore, switch to realtime database then you will se Url.[image]

Like in the above image choose Realtime Database Option then you will see the url.